# Regexp to get website name from a link?

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to get the website name from link, for example if the give link is

```
http://www.example.com/Something/SomethingElse/SomethingUnwanted/Usefulthing.zip
```

I want to get just `www.example.com` out of it. The links are hundreds, so manual work is useless. Therefore I'm tring regexp with something like `sed`.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can make it:

```
sed -r 's|(.*://)?([^/]*).*|\2|' file
```

It handles both urls with and without `http` / `ftp`...:

```
$ cat a
http://www.example.com/Something/SomethingElse/SomethingUnwanted/Usefulthing.zip
www.example.com/Something/SomethingElse/SomethingUnwanted/Usefulthing.zip

$ sed -r 's|(.*://)?([^/]*).*|\2|' a
www.example.com
www.example.com
```

Comment: Although other answers solved the problem as well, I selected this answer because of an unknown reason :P

Comment: Hahhaah that is such a reason, @RegisteredUser :D

Answer (score 2):

With (GNU) grep:

```
grep -oP '(?<=//)[^/]*' <<<"$url"
```

I'm using a positive lookbehind assertion, which is available only in perl compatible mode `-P`.

---

(Original answer)

With `sed`:

```
sed 's#.*//\([^/]*\).*#\1#' <<<"$url"
```

Comment: @fedorqui Thank you! :) I like those lookaheads and -behinds. The idea of having an assertion but don't include it into the match is great! Thanks to perl developers! Unfortunately they are available with GNU grep only. (BSD grep knows option -P but just outputs "... not supported")

Comment: They are extremely handy, I discovered them here in SO a while ago... and cannot help using them more and more. Didn't know about not being available on BSD. From what I see in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BSD_operating_systems#General_information it means that for example OS X cannot use them. So bad...

Comment: @fedorqui Yes, unfortunately all BSD variants (like OS X) can't use `-P` unless GNU grep will get installed on that systems. (Which is possible). I would like to see some GNU extensions getting a POSIX standard since they are making sense but I guess this is *really* hard to achieve. (At least harder than developing the extensions :) )

Answer (score 1):

Try this also,

```
$ sed 's/^http:\/\/\([^/]*\).*/\1/g' file
www.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using regular expressions, you could use the Perl module [`URI::URL`](http://search.cpan.org/~rse/lcwa-1.0.0/lib/lwp/lib/URI/URL.pm). Assuming your list of links is in a file named `links`, this will print out all of the hostnames:

```
perl -MURI::URL -ne '$url = url $_; print $url->host' links
```

Sample input:

```
http://www.example.com/Something/SomethingElse/SomethingUnwanted/Usefulthing.zip                                                                                                                               
http://www.other.example.org/Something/SomethingElse/SomethingUnwanted/Usefulthing.zip                                                                                                                         
http://www.third.net/Something/SomethingElse/SomethingUnwanted/Usefulthing.zip
```

Output:

```
www.example.com
www.other.example.org
www.third.net
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:  `/\/{2}(.*?)\//` it will find anything between // and /

Answer (score 0):

Use **grep** Utility eg.

```
echo 'http://www.example.com/Something/SomethingElse/SomethingUnwanted/Usefulthing.zip' | grep -o 'http://[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*/'
```